# Работа с положением курсора в тексте

Tags: javascript

Пишу фишку с добавлением смайлов. Для добавления использую такую функцию:

```
  function AddSmile(smile) {
  document.getElementById('mess').value=document.getElementById('mess').value+smile; return false;
  }
```

Всё работает, но как и по коду понятно - добавляет только в конец поля. Как можно работать с указателем? Ну т.е. добавлять туда где стоит курсор. В любое место поля.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно определить позицию каретки, либо начало и конец «выделения» и вставить нужное место ([пример](http://jsfiddle.net/79euw/)).

А вот хорошие ответы на эту тему:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373056/913555
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308292/inserting-text-at-cursor-in-a-textarea-with-javascript/3308539#3308539